# Apache Spark Creating new RDD using lineage info from existing RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I get an RDD(child)  from an RDD(root) after multiple transformations.

When i load a new version of root RDD say RDD(root new version),

i would like to recompute RDD(child) using combination of

1)lineage information from existing RDD(root)

2)RDD(root new version).

Can anyone please let me know if its feasible ?

Regards,
SV